# Checking if a Class<?> is instance of other by reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, instanceof, typeof

I'm trying to create a random generator of any class for stress test purposes.

My generator goals to create any class with default constructor and fill its primitive and String fields (by reflection)

I would like also to fill fields of type Number (Integer, Long, Double....) as they are easily convertible to primitives.

But I couldn't find a simple approach o `instanceof` between types.

Here is the method

```
public static <V> Collection<V> createMassiveCollection(Class<V> clazz, int amount, Class<?> collectionType) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        Random r = new Random();
        RandomGenerator rg = new RandomGenerator();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Collection<V> collection = (Collection<V>) collectionType.newInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            V item = clazz.newInstance();

            for (Field field : item.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

                if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) || java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers()))
                    continue;

                field.setAccessible(true);

                if (field.getType().equals(String.class))
                    field.set(item, rg.nextCompliment());

                else if (field.getType().isPrimitive() && (field.getType() != boolean.class && field.getType() != byte.class && field.getType() != char.class))
                    field.set(item, r.nextInt(1000000));

                else {
                    Constructor<?> c = null;

                    try {
                        c = field.getType().getConstructor(String.class);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {}
                    if (c != null && Number.class.isInstance(c.newInstance("1")))
                        field.set(item, field.getType().getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(r.nextInt(1000000) + ""));
                }

            }

            collection.add(item);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

The third if is the one causing problems
I would like something like: "if `Type<C>` is subtype of `Type<V>`"
but all ways i found need an valid instance of object to check.

ex.
`Number.class.isInstance(field.getType())` nor `field.getType() instanceof Number` works because `field.getType()` is instance of Type.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Another question (less important) in my method signature i would like to have

```
Class<? extends Collection<V>> collectionType
```

but if i do that when i try to call the method like

```
createMassiveCollection(User.class, 100000, new ArrayList<User>().getClass());
```

the compiler fails! so, to be able to compile i must trust the user is passing some type that extends Collection as parameter

Comment: `new ArrayList<User>().getClass()` always returns *erased* type `Class<? extends ArrayList<?>>`, so it's only possible to obtain `Class<? extends Collection<V>>` by "unsafe" casting. And you shouldn't actually even need to do that, because `Class<? extends Collection<?>>` is perfectly fine for your needs: who ACTUALLY cares if that collection type is `<V>` if you create and fill new collection anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a class is a subclass of another you have to use `isAssignableFrom`:

```
if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) { // ...
```

For your 2nd question you need a 2nd generic:

```
public static <V, C extends Collection<?>> Collection<V> createMassiveCollection(Class<V> clazz, int amount, Class<C> collectionType)
```

You can define this generic also as `C extends Collection<V>` but this creates a compiler warning and does not prevent an invokation like `createMassiveCollection(String.class, 10, new ArrayList<Number>().getClass())`.

By the way, my last parameter would by `ArrayList.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Class#isAssignableFrom()` which allows to determine whether one class is a subtype of another one. Example:

```
System.out.println(String.class.isAssignableFrom(Object.class));
System.out.println(Object.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class));
```

It outputs

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `field.getType()` do return `Class<?>`. The `type` property name comes from Java 1, when there is no generics and thus no `Type` interface. It may be confusing at the first glance though.
2. To test if the class a `Class<?>` represents is a subtype of the class represented by another `Class<?>` you will need to use `classA.isAssignableFrom(classB)`. e.g. `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)` will return true.
3. It's possible but pointless to write `Class<? extends Collection<V>> collectionType`, because you can't get an instance of `Class<? extends Collection<V>>` without explicit unsafe casts. Because

   1. [Attempting to write class literals of generic types, except a wildcard type, will result in compile time errors.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)
   2. `Object.getClass()` will return the erased type. e.g. The type of the return value of `new ArrayList<User>().getClass()` will be `ArrayList` or `ArrayList<?>`, whose meanings are identical.

   Without explicit unsafe casts, this method can only be called when `V` is a wildcard.